# Change multiple if to a loop?

Tags: c, loops, if-statement

I've just learned how to use loops, but I cant figure out how to translate this code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    float manyTest, gr1, gr2, gr3, gr4, gr5, gr6, gr7, gr8, gr9, gr10, gr11, gr12, gr13, gr14, gr15, gr16, gr17, gr18, gr19, gr20, gr21, gr22, gr23, gr24, gr25;
    manyTest = gr1 = gr2 = gr3 = gr4 = gr5 = gr6 = gr7 = gr8 = gr9 = gr10 = gr11 = gr12 = gr13 = gr14 = gr15 = gr16 = gr17 = gr18 = gr19 = gr20 = gr21 = gr22 = gr23 = gr24 = gr25 = 0;

    printf("How many tests you wanna average? (Minimum 1 Maximum 25)\n");
    scanf(" %f", &manyTest);
    if (manyTest <= 0) {
        printf("The Minimum is 1!\n");

    }
    else if (manyTest > 25){
        printf("The Maximum is 25!\n");

    }
    else {
        if (manyTest == 1) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
        }
        else if (manyTest == 2) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
        }
        else if (manyTest == 3) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);

        }
        else if (manyTest == 4) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);

        }
        else if (manyTest == 5) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);
            scanf(" %f", &gr5);
        }
        else if (manyTest == 6) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);
            scanf(" %f", &gr5);
            scanf(" %f", &gr6);

        }
        else if (manyTest == 7) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);
            scanf(" %f", &gr5);
            scanf(" %f", &gr6);
            scanf(" %f", &gr7);
        }
        else if (manyTest == 8) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);
            scanf(" %f", &gr5);
            scanf(" %f", &gr6);
            scanf(" %f", &gr7);
            scanf(" %f", &gr8);
        }
        else if (manyTest == 9) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);
            scanf(" %f", &gr5);
            scanf(" %f", &gr6);
            scanf(" %f", &gr7);
            scanf(" %f", &gr8);
            scanf(" %f", &gr9);
        }
        else if (manyTest == 10) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);
            scanf(" %f", &gr5);
            scanf(" %f", &gr6);
            scanf(" %f", &gr7);
            scanf(" %f", &gr8);
            scanf(" %f", &gr9);
            scanf(" %f", &gr10);
        }
        else if (manyTest == 11) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);
            scanf(" %f", &gr5);
            scanf(" %f", &gr6);
            scanf(" %f", &gr7);
            scanf(" %f", &gr8);
            scanf(" %f", &gr9);
            scanf(" %f", &gr10);
            scanf(" %f", &gr11);
        }
        else if (manyTest == 12) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);
            scanf(" %f", &gr5);
            scanf(" %f", &gr6);
            scanf(" %f", &gr7);
            scanf(" %f", &gr8);
            scanf(" %f", &gr9);
            scanf(" %f", &gr10);
            scanf(" %f", &gr11);
            scanf(" %f", &gr12);
        }
        else if (manyTest == 13) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);
            scanf(" %f", &gr5);
            scanf(" %f", &gr6);
            scanf(" %f", &gr7);
            scanf(" %f", &gr8);
            scanf(" %f", &gr9);
            scanf(" %f", &gr10);
            scanf(" %f", &gr11);
            scanf(" %f", &gr12);
            scanf(" %f", &gr13);
        }
        else if (manyTest == 14) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);
            scanf(" %f", &gr5);
            scanf(" %f", &gr6);
            scanf(" %f", &gr7);
            scanf(" %f", &gr8);
            scanf(" %f", &gr9);
            scanf(" %f", &gr10);
            scanf(" %f", &gr11);
            scanf(" %f", &gr12);
            scanf(" %f", &gr13);
            scanf(" %f", &gr14);
        }
        else if (manyTest == 15) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);
            scanf(" %f", &gr5);
            scanf(" %f", &gr6);
            scanf(" %f", &gr7);
            scanf(" %f", &gr8);
            scanf(" %f", &gr9);
            scanf(" %f", &gr10);
            scanf(" %f", &gr11);
            scanf(" %f", &gr12);
            scanf(" %f", &gr13);
            scanf(" %f", &gr14);
            scanf(" %f", &gr15);
        }
        else if (manyTest == 16) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);
            scanf(" %f", &gr5);
            scanf(" %f", &gr6);
            scanf(" %f", &gr7);
            scanf(" %f", &gr8);
            scanf(" %f", &gr9);
            scanf(" %f", &gr10);
            scanf(" %f", &gr11);
            scanf(" %f", &gr12);
            scanf(" %f", &gr13);
            scanf(" %f", &gr14);
            scanf(" %f", &gr15);
            scanf(" %f", &gr16);
        }
        else if (manyTest == 17) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);
            scanf(" %f", &gr5);
            scanf(" %f", &gr6);
            scanf(" %f", &gr7);
            scanf(" %f", &gr8);
            scanf(" %f", &gr9);
            scanf(" %f", &gr10);
            scanf(" %f", &gr11);
            scanf(" %f", &gr12);
            scanf(" %f", &gr13);
            scanf(" %f", &gr14);
            scanf(" %f", &gr15);
            scanf(" %f", &gr16);
            scanf(" %f", &gr17);
        }
        else if (manyTest == 18) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);
            scanf(" %f", &gr5);
            scanf(" %f", &gr6);
            scanf(" %f", &gr7);
            scanf(" %f", &gr8);
            scanf(" %f", &gr9);
            scanf(" %f", &gr10);
            scanf(" %f", &gr11);
            scanf(" %f", &gr12);
            scanf(" %f", &gr13);
            scanf(" %f", &gr14);
            scanf(" %f", &gr15);
            scanf(" %f", &gr16);
            scanf(" %f", &gr17);
            scanf(" %f", &gr18);
        }
        else if (manyTest == 19) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);
            scanf(" %f", &gr5);
            scanf(" %f", &gr6);
            scanf(" %f", &gr7);
            scanf(" %f", &gr8);
            scanf(" %f", &gr9);
            scanf(" %f", &gr10);
            scanf(" %f", &gr11);
            scanf(" %f", &gr12);
            scanf(" %f", &gr13);
            scanf(" %f", &gr14);
            scanf(" %f", &gr15);
            scanf(" %f", &gr16);
            scanf(" %f", &gr17);
            scanf(" %f", &gr18);
            scanf(" %f", &gr19);
        }
        else if (manyTest == 20) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);
            scanf(" %f", &gr5);
            scanf(" %f", &gr6);
            scanf(" %f", &gr7);
            scanf(" %f", &gr8);
            scanf(" %f", &gr9);
            scanf(" %f", &gr10);
            scanf(" %f", &gr11);
            scanf(" %f", &gr12);
            scanf(" %f", &gr13);
            scanf(" %f", &gr14);
            scanf(" %f", &gr15);
            scanf(" %f", &gr16);
            scanf(" %f", &gr17);
            scanf(" %f", &gr18);
            scanf(" %f", &gr19);
            scanf(" %f", &gr20);
        }
        else if (manyTest == 21) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);
            scanf(" %f", &gr5);
            scanf(" %f", &gr6);
            scanf(" %f", &gr7);
            scanf(" %f", &gr8);
            scanf(" %f", &gr9);
            scanf(" %f", &gr10);
            scanf(" %f", &gr11);
            scanf(" %f", &gr12);
            scanf(" %f", &gr13);
            scanf(" %f", &gr14);
            scanf(" %f", &gr15);
            scanf(" %f", &gr16);
            scanf(" %f", &gr17);
            scanf(" %f", &gr18);
            scanf(" %f", &gr19);
            scanf(" %f", &gr20);
            scanf(" %f", &gr21);
        }
        else if (manyTest == 22) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);
            scanf(" %f", &gr5);
            scanf(" %f", &gr6);
            scanf(" %f", &gr7);
            scanf(" %f", &gr8);
            scanf(" %f", &gr9);
            scanf(" %f", &gr10);
            scanf(" %f", &gr11);
            scanf(" %f", &gr12);
            scanf(" %f", &gr13);
            scanf(" %f", &gr14);
            scanf(" %f", &gr15);
            scanf(" %f", &gr16);
            scanf(" %f", &gr17);
            scanf(" %f", &gr18);
            scanf(" %f", &gr19);
            scanf(" %f", &gr20);
            scanf(" %f", &gr21);
            scanf(" %f", &gr22);
        }
        else if (manyTest == 23) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);
            scanf(" %f", &gr5);
            scanf(" %f", &gr6);
            scanf(" %f", &gr7);
            scanf(" %f", &gr8);
            scanf(" %f", &gr9);
            scanf(" %f", &gr10);
            scanf(" %f", &gr11);
            scanf(" %f", &gr12);
            scanf(" %f", &gr13);
            scanf(" %f", &gr14);
            scanf(" %f", &gr15);
            scanf(" %f", &gr16);
            scanf(" %f", &gr17);
            scanf(" %f", &gr18);
            scanf(" %f", &gr19);
            scanf(" %f", &gr20);
            scanf(" %f", &gr21);
            scanf(" %f", &gr22);
            scanf(" %f", &gr23);
        }
        else if (manyTest == 24) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);
            scanf(" %f", &gr5);
            scanf(" %f", &gr6);
            scanf(" %f", &gr7);
            scanf(" %f", &gr8);
            scanf(" %f", &gr9);
            scanf(" %f", &gr10);
            scanf(" %f", &gr11);
            scanf(" %f", &gr12);
            scanf(" %f", &gr13);
            scanf(" %f", &gr14);
            scanf(" %f", &gr15);
            scanf(" %f", &gr16);
            scanf(" %f", &gr17);
            scanf(" %f", &gr18);
            scanf(" %f", &gr19);
            scanf(" %f", &gr20);
            scanf(" %f", &gr21);
            scanf(" %f", &gr22);
            scanf(" %f", &gr23);
            scanf(" %f", &gr24);
        }
        else if (manyTest == 25) {
            printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
            scanf(" %f", &gr1);
            scanf(" %f", &gr2);
            scanf(" %f", &gr3);
            scanf(" %f", &gr4);
            scanf(" %f", &gr5);
            scanf(" %f", &gr6);
            scanf(" %f", &gr7);
            scanf(" %f", &gr8);
            scanf(" %f", &gr9);
            scanf(" %f", &gr10);
            scanf(" %f", &gr11);
            scanf(" %f", &gr12);
            scanf(" %f", &gr13);
            scanf(" %f", &gr14);
            scanf(" %f", &gr15);
            scanf(" %f", &gr16);
            scanf(" %f", &gr17);
            scanf(" %f", &gr18);
            scanf(" %f", &gr19);
            scanf(" %f", &gr20);
            scanf(" %f", &gr21);
            scanf(" %f", &gr22);
            scanf(" %f", &gr23);
            scanf(" %f", &gr24);
            scanf(" %f", &gr25);
        }
        float avg = (gr1 + gr2 + gr3 + gr4 + gr5 + gr6 + gr7 + gr8 + gr9 + gr10 + gr11 + gr12 + gr13 + gr14 + gr15 + gr16 + gr17 + gr18 + gr19 + gr20 + gr21 + gr22 + gr23 + gr24 + gr25) / manyTest;
        printf("Your average grade is: %.2f\n", avg);

    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

from all of those `if...if...if...if....if` to some single loops. As you can see, my code is VERY long, and I made it just before I learned how to use loops. So, now after I've learned I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Use a loop and an array.

Comment: You need to use array instead of your variables `gr1, gr2`

Comment: You can't loop over different variables, but you can loop over an array.

Comment: How would you write that code if th Maximum was 100 ?

Comment: You have used `scanf()` wrong and so many times! Why don't you use an array? is it forbidden?

Comment: @KerrekSB, actually, he shouldn't use an array, because the job doesn't require knowing each value - only the running total :)

Comment: Bear in mind that loops do not necessarily translate well to branching operations.

Comment: @Roddy: yes, true -- see my answer :-)

Comment: for readability and understandability by us humans, please follow the axiom: only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.

Comment: can the user of this code perform a fraction of a test?  Probably not, so the variable: `manyTest` should be an integer, not a float

Comment: the 'pause' command is not available in all OS shells.  suggest: `int ch; while( (ch = getchar())!= EOF && '\n' != ch );  getchar();`

Comment: `float` values do not always exactly equal some integer value, so the comparisons to integer literals can fail.  Suggest replacing: `float manyTest` with 'int manyTest;`  or, in other words, never perform a `==` for a float value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is simply a loop for your `manyTest` value, you **do not need array at all**!

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    float manyTest = 0, gr = 0, avg = 0; //firstly, replace many gr with single gr, avg for averaging
    int i; //just indexer

    printf("How many tests you wanna average? (Minimum 1 Maximum 25)\n");
    scanf(" %f", &manyTest);
    if (manyTest <= 0) {
        printf("The Minimum is 1!\n");
    }
    else if (manyTest > 25){
        printf("The Maximum is 25!\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Write down your grades on those tests:\n");
        for (i = 0; i < manyTest; ++i) {
            scanf(" %f", &gr); //use gr every time
            avg += gr; //then immediately add to avg!
        }
        printf("Your average grade is: %.2f\n", avg / manyTest); //notice the division by manyTest
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Done!

Sample result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array , and iterate over to take inputs .

Some thing like this could be done -

```
int n;                          // number of tests
scanf("%d",&n);                 // take input number of tests 
int grades[n];                  // declare your array 
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){           // loop for n times
   scanf(" %d",&grades[i]);     // take input n number of grades 
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to pass over the newline character.

Comment: isn't the question is about reducing the if..else?

Comment: @Bathsheba I never said it's bad, just the priorities, you know. :)

Comment: @Bathsheba Sir , I didn't really understand your first comment clearly.

Comment: Methinks you need `scanf(" %` in the `for` loop. Note the space

Comment: @Bathsheba I thought so , but Sir,  wont `%d` ignore that ?

Comment: I don't think so. Try it. See also the accepted answer.

Comment: @Bathsheba It didn't anything wired while running ,but nevertheless I will add that .

Answer (score 1):

Here's a relatively robust and complete example that doesn't restrict the total amount of input. Rather, you send EOF to end the input stream:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int total = 0;
  double acc = 0, val;

  for (;;) {
    fputs("Value: ", stdout);
    fflush(stdout);

    errno = 0;
    int res = fscanf(stdin, "%lf", &val);

    if (res == EOF) {
      // Handle successful end of input or read error.
      if (errno == 0) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Done! You entered %d values averaging %f.\n",
                total, acc / total);
      } else {
        fputs("There was an error, aborting!\n", stdout);
      }
      break;
    } else if (res == 0) {
      // Handle parse error.
      fputs("Sorry, I did not understand. Try again.\n", stdout);
      clearerr(stdin);
      for (int r = 0; r != EOF && r != '\n'; r = fgetc(stdin)) {}
    } else {
      // Handle successful input.
      acc += val;
      ++total;
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/c1RhsT)

Comment: I hope there's enough bugs in that to ensure copy/pasting it would get a poor grade :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a way to calculate the average of a set of numbers without storing each one individually, either in an array, or in individually names variable (yuk.)

Just keep a running total, and divide it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the first part, regarding reducing the `if...else` condition checks you cannot remove *all* your `if..else` condition from your code,  however, you can reduce your `else` part for sure. You need to use a [`switch` statement](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/switch_statement_in_c.htm) for that purpose. Something like

```
if (manyTest <= 0) {
    printf("The Minimum is 1!\n");

}
else if (manyTest > 25){
    printf("The Maximum is 25!\n");

}
else {
    switch(manyTest)
    {

       case 1: //.... break;
       case 2: //..... break;
    }
```

can be of your help.

Then, to reduce the number of variable used in your code, you can make use of an [array](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm), and use a `for` loop to iterate certain number of times to fill the required number of inputs.

Comment: Thanks tho, but I dont know how to use the switch statement.
Can you explain me how to do it or you say I should keep learning until I will be able to use it?

Comment: @kuyy Then it's high time you learn that. I've updated my answer with a link to a simple tutorial. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple array for your for grade input and for average, Its just one step ahead for your

```
int main()
{
    int manyTest = 0;
    float gr[25];

    printf("How many tests you wanna average? (Minimum 1 Maximum 25)\n");
    scanf(" %f", &manyTest);
    if (manyTest <= 0) {
        printf("The Minimum is 1!\n");

    }
    else if (manyTest > 25){
        printf("The Maximum is 25!\n");

    }
    for(int i=0;i<manyTest;i++){
        printf("Write down your grades for test %d:",i);
         scanf(" %f", &gr[i]);
    }
//Average
    float avg;
    for(int j=0; j<manyTest;j++){
        avg+=gr[j];
    }
    avg=(avg/manyTest);
    printf("Your average grade is: %.2f\n", avg);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work well. It just keep asking me forever "blahlahlahl grade for test *number*"

Comment: grade for test is in for loop, and it runs exactly same time as your input for *manyTest*